# Converting a std_logic_vector to integer within Process to test values?

Tags: vhdl, xilinx, xilinx-ise

What I'm trying to do is pretty simple, just generating a pulse from a basic counter. My code is shown below.  My question is if there's an efficient way of comparing a std_logic_vector and an integer?  I only need to compare them at that one instance in the process.  Also, can you do aritmetic on a 4 bit signal as shown in my code?  DO you need a specific library?

```
signal Top16: std_logic; -- 1 clk spike at 16x baud rate    
signal Div16: std_logic_vector(3 downto 0);

DIVISOR: natural := 120 -- Can be 120 or 60, depending on user preference.    
------------------------------------------------------------------------

    process (RST, LCLK_MULT_BUFG)
    begin
        if RST='1' then
            Top16 <= '0';  --1 bit signal
            Div16 <= x"0";  -- 4 bit signal
        elsif rising_edge(LCLK_MULT_BUFG) then
            Top16 <= '0';
                if Div16 = Divisor then  -----> signal to integer comparison?
                    Div16 <= 0;
                    Top16 <= '1';  
                else
                    Div16 <= Div16 + 1;   -----arithmetic on std_logic_vector??
                end if;
        end if;
```

### **EDIT:**

The number of bits within the Div16 std_logic_vector will vary depending on the size of Divisor chosen (shown below).  How to correctly format this?  What libraries will be needed?

```
DIVISOR: natural := 120 -- Can be 120 or 60, depending on user preference.
constant COUNTER_BITS : natural := integer(ceil(log2(real(DIVISOR))));
signal Div16: std_logic_vector(COUNTER_BITS);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If at all possible, avoid the non-standard `std_logic_unsigned` library. It would be better to use `numeric_std` and declare Div16 as `unsigned`.

```
signal Div16: unsigned(3 downto 0);
```

Then your comparison and arithmetic should simply work. And of course it's synthesisable.

Your bonus question should also be synthesisable though DIVISOR ought to be a CONSTANT so that it can be evaluated at compile time, and I think you meant

```
signal Div16: unsigned(COUNTER_BITS - 1 downto 0);
```

Comment: Is that signal still fully synthesizable?   Also added an edit above for another conversion issue, would really appreciate if you could check that one out too!

Comment: am still recieving these 2 errors when I try what you say:      "ERROR:HDLCompiler:69 - *Line 62*: <ceil> is not declared."                    
"ERROR:HDLCompiler:622 - *Line 62*: Near integer ; type conversion expression type cannot be determined uniquely"

Comment: Since ceil() was in your code I assumed you'd already found it. It's in the ieee.math_real library so just use that : `use ieee.math_real.all;` with the other `use` clauses. If you don't want to use math_real, a ceil function is trivial to write. The second error is just a consequence of not finding ceil.

Answer (score 0):

For the arithmetic you can use `std_logic_unsigned`. This library contains the following functions:

```
function "+"(L: STD_LOGIC_VECTOR; R: INTEGER) return STD_LOGIC_VECTOR;
function "+"(L: INTEGER; R: STD_LOGIC_VECTOR) return STD_LOGIC_VECTOR;
```

For the comparison you can just leave it like this if you are using `std_logic_unsigned`. This library contains the following functions:

```
function "="(L: STD_LOGIC_VECTOR; R: INTEGER) return BOOLEAN;
function "="(L: INTEGER; R: STD_LOGIC_VECTOR) return BOOLEAN;
```

You could also define Div16 as `unsigned` and then use `numeric_std`. This library contains the following functions for comparison:

```
function "=" ( L: NATURAL; R: UNSIGNED) return BOOLEAN;
function "=" ( L: UNSIGNED; R: NATURAL) return BOOLEAN;
```

And for the addition:

```
function "+" ( L: UNSIGNED; R: NATURAL) return UNSIGNED;
function "+" ( L: NATURAL; R: UNSIGNED) return UNSIGNED;
```